# ElementReference to conditionally created element in Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to set focus to input control which is conditionally rendered. I'm setting `ElementReference` but it's id and context are both null.

```cs
<button @onclick="ToggleInput">Show input</button>
@if(showInput) {
    <input @ref="inputRef" type="text"/>
}

@code {
    private ElementReference inputRef;
    private bool showInput;

    async void ToggleInput() {
        showInput = !showInput;

        await inputRef.FocusAsync();
    }
}
```

When I press the button it shows this error in console:

> System.InvalidOperationException: ElementReference has not been configured correctly

Full error message:

[image]

Working example with error https://blazorrepl.com/repl/wbueaMPK28hf2NNv09

Comment: You could set it to be optional with a `?` So `await inputRef?.FocusAsync()`? Or just wrap a null check

Comment: Yeah, but this reference never will be set and I'd like to know what I have to do to makes it working.

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond, `ElementReference` will never be null as it is a `struct`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to work and didn't have to be a separate component. I stuck it right on the start page.

```
<button @onclick="ToggleInput">Show input</button>
@if (showInput)
{
    <input @ref="inputRef" type="text" />
}

@code {
    private ElementReference inputRef;
    private bool showInput;

    protected async override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (showInput) await inputRef.FocusAsync();
    }

    void ToggleInput()
    {
        showInput = !showInput;
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks!

Comment: this will be focusing the input on each render once the input is shown!

Answer (score 2):

It's not the perfect solution either, more like a workaround, but the following worked for me:

```
<button @onclick="ToggleInput">Show input</button>
@if(showInput) {
    <input @ref="inputRef" type="text"/>
}

@code {
    private ElementReference inputRef;
    private bool showInput;

    async void ToggleInput() {
        showInput = !showInput;
        StateHasChanged();
        
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            if(inputRef.Context != null) inputRef.FocusAsync();
        });
    }
}
```

In my tests, the context was never null, so it probably wouldn't need the check. But I prefer that the focus is not set than that an exception would be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Move the input box to another component. Then you can then hook into the lifecycle of the component and call `.FocusAsync` after it has rendered.

https://blazorrepl.com/repl/cluoEsvU59fl8zYM22

Comment: Please consider put whatever code you have here instead of a link; I know my work firewall / proxy blocks the dlls from this site and I can't see what's actually posted, others might have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly cleaner solution:

```
<button @onclick="ToggleInput">Show input</button>
@if(showInput) {
    <input @ref="inputRef" type="text"/>
}

@code {
    private ElementReference inputRef;
    private bool showInput;

    async void ToggleInput() {
        showInput = !showInput;
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        await inputRef.FocusAsync();
    }
}
```