# How to focus an element when making it visible in the same method call?

Tags: async-await, blazor

I have this (simplified) component where the user input a value and presses enter. This should cause the input to disappear until a process has completed and then the input should show again.

```cs
@if (!commandRunning)
{
    <div class="action">
        <div class="command">
            <span class="symbol">></span>
            <input @ref="input" class="in" type="text" @bind-value="@_command" @bind-value:event="oninput" @onkeypress="@(e => KeyPressed(e))">
        </div>
    </div>
}

@code {

    private string _command { get; set; }

    private bool commandRunning;

    private ElementReference input;


    private async Task KeyPressed(KeyboardEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Key == "Enter")
        {

            commandRunning = true;
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            commandRunning = false;

            await input.FocusAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

This however causes the following error:

```
blazor.webassembly.js:1 crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Unable to focus an invalid element.
      Error: Unable to focus an invalid element.
```

So the input has not yet been created at the point of focusing.

Altering the code by adding StateHasChanged() before the focus call makes it work however.

```cs
commandRunning = true;
await Task.Delay(1000);
commandRunning = false;
StateHasChanged();
await input.FocusAsync();
```

Is this the expected behaviour? Is the changed bool not evaluated in the razor code until after the method has been executed?

Comment: Instead of 'hiding' the textbox, won't it be fancier for your viewers to see a flickering textbox, perhaps with changing colors ;} Now seriously, do you really mean to hide the textbox, and then restore it ? This is very bad. Don't do that. Just disable the textbox.

Comment: Put your input in another component. Use the new components cycle to manage its focus.

Comment: I should have explained the reasoning behind the code. It is used to emulate a console terminal. A user inputs something, presses enter and the input gets hidden, a command gets executed and when it is done, the user may now input again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every event in the UI has two steps, the call to the event handler followed by a call to `StateHasChanged`.  If the event handler returns a `Task` then the caller waits on it's completion before calling `StateHasChanged`.  If it returns a `void` then `StateHasChanged` is called when the event handler yields (which may or may not be when it completes).

Let's look at what you have set up.

```
<input @ref="input" class="in" type="text" @bind-value="@_command" @bind-value:event="oninput" @onkeypress="@(e => KeyPressed(e))">
```

1. `input` value is wired to `_command` and set to update every time the user enters a value (at every keystroke including an *enter*).
2. `onkeypress` is wired up `KeyPressed` and fire on every keypress.

You have two events kicking off whenever the user enters a value.

Now to `KeyPressed`

```
    commandRunning = true;
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    commandRunning = false;

    await input.FocusAsync();
```

The first `await` yields control back to the UI thread which almost certainly updates `_command` and fires `StateHasChanged` at the completion of that event.  With `Commandrunning` set to `false` the html elements are wiped out and cease to exist.

After the `TaskDelay` completes, `commandRunning` is set back to `true`.  You then try to set the focus to `input` which doesn't exist (the component hasn't been re-rendered and input created).  Adding the `StateHasChanged` before `FocusAsync` re-renders the component, setting up all the html elements including `input`.
After `KeyPressed` completes `StateHasChanged` is called by the orginating event (which doesn't do anything new).

To ensure what you want to do works correctly:

```
    private async Task KeyPressed(KeyboardEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Key == "Enter")
        {
            commandRunning = true;
            // make sure the UI has re-rendered and the html is destroyed
            await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
            //  Do whatever you're doing
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            commandRunning = false;
            // make sure the UI has re-rendered and the html is re-built
            await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
            await input.FocusAsync();
        }
    }
```

[Polite] Not sure why you should want to hide and then re-display the input, but.... it's your code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I should have explained the reasoning behind the code. It is used to emulate a console terminal. A user inputs something, presses enter and the input gets hidden, a command gets executed and when it is done, the user may now input again.

Comment: There is no reason to Invoke the StatehasChanged() call. And no effect, it is synchronous.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - Yes agreed in this situation.  But, there are times when you need to invoke it when the event handler isn't running on the UI thread.  This is a public domain answer, someone may copy this code and run it in such a situation, so I've taken the belt and braces approach in the answer.

Answer (score 7):

> Is this the expected behaviour?

Yes.

There is an implied StateHasChanged() before and after an event like KeyPressed. StateHasChanged queues a render, it does not immediately execute it. The code path needs to `await` something for the actual rendering to happen.

So when you need multiple 'updates' in your method you do need to call it yourself.

And in your solution the Rendering is happening somewhere *during* the `input.FocusAsync()`.
I would go  for safe with:

```
commandRunning = false;
StateHasChanged();
await Task.Delay(1);   // allow the rendering to happen
await input.FocusAsync();
```

Comment: So if any await is made right after the StateHasChanged() call I can be sure that the input is there?

Comment: No, the awaited method could be 'fake' async. You have to know. Task.Delay() is more reliable but I'm not sure, maybe it can be overwhelmed. Test the input reference always.

Comment: Couldn't you simply set the focus in `OnAfterRenderAsync`, as [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67008948/107625) suggests?

Comment: @UweKeim - maybe, depends on how much control the user has over setting the focus elsewhere. OnAfterRender could move the focus when it's not called for.